# How to Place the token on my site in google site verification process

Tags: node.js, google-api

Hi i'm unable to verify site in site verification process.

**Step 1:** verification token by calling getToken method

**This is the response i'm getting from step1:**

{
  "token": "google12cfc68677988bb4.html",
  "method": "FILE"
}

**Step 2:** Place the token on your site using whatever method you choose.

My question is how to place token (google12cfc68677988bb4.html) on site.I stuck in step 2.
can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

## Using Express : Serve Static

You can set up a public dir, and serve the static .html file from
    there:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(7777, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 7777!')
})
```

So with : `app.use(express.static('public'));` you are telling express to use the folder called public for serving static files.

Create the **public** directory, include the google verification .html inside and try to access it (`localhost:7777/google12cfc68677988bb4.html`)

---

## Using Express : GET Route

```
app.get('/google12cfc68677988bb4.html', function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname+"/google12cfc68677988bb4.html");
})
```

(I would go for the serve static instead)